# Error java.nio.file.FileSystemException occured on installing gerrit trigger in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I'm completely stuck with Gerrit Trigger install. The Gerrit trigger plugin version is 2.27.2 in Jenkins plugin manager. 
please refer to the error message as below

[image]

[image]

the java.exe process is necessary for Jenkins service, so I can't end it.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

due to gerrit-trigger.xml under Jenkins root directory which should be deleted before installing